# Shlobj.h актуален?

Tags: c++, winapi

Здравствуйте! Пишу простой проводник и столкнулся с такой библиотекой. Вопрос такой: для написания проводника ею лучше пользоваться? И для современных windows она актуально или что то новое придумали?

Comment: Это не библиотека, а заголовочный файл. Описано в нем очень много всего, следовательно говорить "лучше" и "актуально" нельзя.

Comment: Я к тому, что в 2016 для создания простого проводника этот заголовочный файл использовать?

Comment: используйте если надо. Если не надо - не используйте. Предлагаете угадать что за технологии у вас там и что именно из этого хидера вам надо? Не выйдет...

Comment: VS15 c++ winapi без mfc. Как по вашему лучше делать проводник?

Comment: В shlobj заложено много технологий, точнее ключи доступа к "Мой Компьтер", "Корзина", доступ к системному контекстному меню, и т.д. если вам функционал библиотеки нужен - подключайте. Я использовал этот файл что б наследывать рабочий стол и зареестрироваться как легальный "проводник" через IShellFolderViewCB и IShellBrowser.

Comment: @helldrg по моему лучше его не делать вовсе, когда файловых менеджеров и так полно.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов Дело в том, что задание такое в институте =) Вот разобрался как пользоваться tree view элементом, как winpai средствами перебирать файлы в директории и записывать их в дерево, но не понял как записывать элемент на 3 уровне, т.е. я раскрываю C:\ элемент там нажимаю на windows элемент, но узнать что в этой папке находится не могу так как пути нету, только имя. В поисках решения этой проблемы натолкнулся на Sholbj.h

Comment: @nick_n_a у вас вроде по расширенней ответ, можете оформить как полагает, буду это использовать если ничего другого нет и это работает на 10

Comment: @helldrg полный путь к каталогу формируется из путей к его родительским каталогам. Не вижу тут надобности в отдельных API-функциях.

Comment: Я думаю само имя *shlobj.h* легко расшифровуется как shell objects. 1. Про них можно почитать на MSDN. 2. Посмотрев содержимое shlobj.h становится понятно нужны эти обьекты или нет. И как вывод: имя библиотеки говорит само за себя, нужна она для более тесной интеграции в оболочку windows, либо для вызова/наследования елементов оболочки (меню, плагины, вызов панели управления, управление корзиной, рабочим столом, меню и другими елементами оболочки). То что такой ответ нужен для базы SO - не думаю.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Вооот, а как мне так сделать или как вопрос задать насчет формирования путей?

Comment: @nick_n_a спасибо, вы все рассказали про это, что я хотел узнать

Comment: @helldrg что сделать? Для каждого каталога храните имя родителя.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов так я храню Parent = (HTREEITEM)SendMessage(treeView, TVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&tvinsert); tvinsert.hParent = Parent;  Как воспользоваться этим?

Comment: "Что сделать?" Я определяю на какой элемент нажимаю 2 раза. У меня появляется его имя, но что бы новые элементы вставить на иеархию ниже, нужно просмотреть какие файлы и папки в той директории находятся, а я этого не могу так как у меня только имя есть, путь я не знаю как сформировать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Дело в том, что задание такое в институте =) Вот разобрался как
>   пользоваться tree view элементом, как winpai средствами перебирать
>   файлы в директории и записывать их в дерево, но не понял как
>   записывать элемент на 3 уровне, т.е. я раскрываю C:\ элемент там
>   нажимаю на windows элемент, но узнать что в этой папке находится не
>   могу так как пути нету, только имя. Дело в том, что задание такое в
>   институте =) Вот разобрался как пользоваться tree view элементом, как
>   winpai средствами перебирать файлы в директории и записывать их в
>   дерево, но не понял как записывать элемент на 3 уровне, т.е. я
>   раскрываю C:\ элемент там нажимаю на windows элемент, но узнать что в
>   этой папке находится не могу так как пути нету, только имя.

Shlobj.h тут не нужен, пользуйтесь функциями findfirst, findnext